# Composer package folder structure created with Laravel 4's "bench" command

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

So, I have created a composer package for Laravel 4 using `php artisan bench --composer`

This is all working great,

But, I was looking through the `Basset` Packages vendor folder, and I noticed that our structures are slightly different.

```
Basset:
/vendor/jasonlewis/basset/src/Basset/BassetServiceProvider.php
Mine:
/vendor/hailwood/smartless4laravel/src/Hailwood/Smartless4laravel/Smartless4laravelServiceProvider.php
```

so basically what we have here is

```
<v> = vendor Lower case,  <p> = package lower case, 
<V> = vendor Upper cased  <P> = package upper cased

Basset:
/<v>/<p>/src/<P>/
Mine:
/<v>/<p>/src/<V>/<P>/
```

So, why is my package nested under the vendor again, or should Basset also be listed under the vendor again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the convention is vendor/package/src/namespace.  If your namespace includes the vendor name, you should probably leave it as is.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so, in that case Basset is breaking the standards?

Comment: Basset breaks the namespacing convention by not including the vendor, but not in the directory structure.  If you take a look at the Laravel source, you'll see it's in laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/... where Illuminate/... is the namespace of the laravel packages.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what it comes down to is you workbench creates a vendor name and package name folder where as in the basset package there is only the package name folder. The Basset package was likely not created with the workbench as I think it has been out longer than the workbench. (newer addition to the framework).

Comment: So is there any reason why i shouldnt move it out of the sub-vendor folder?

Comment: Not necessarily but be aware that you will need to namespace differently.